# Xcode UITesting: label disappears from hierarchy and won't come back

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

This is using Xcode 7.2.1 and Swift 2.0.

I have a table cell containing a `UILabel` which is used to display an error message. So at initial load it is blanked using code like this:

```
cell.errorLabel.alpha = 0.0
cell.errorLabel.text = nil
```

Then later on when I've detected an error I want to display I do this:

```
cell.label.text = "to"
cell.errorLabel.alpha = 1.0
cell.errorLabel.text = "Error !!!!"
```

This works fine when running the app. However when running in a UI Test, I try to test that the error is being displayed like this:

```
let toCell = XCUIApplication().tables.... // Finds the cell with label 'to'
XCTAssertTrue(toCell.staticTexts["Error !!!!"].exists)
```

And it fails. I've verified I'm getting the right cell by checking the other ('to') label is present. Which it is. But the UI testing will not see the error label. I've tested this by adding a break point and using the debugger like this:

```
(lldb) p toCell.staticTexts.count
    t =   427.03s     Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type StaticText
    t =   427.29s         Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for enterprise.com.me
    t =   427.31s         Find: Descendants matching type Table
(UInt) $R2 = 1
    t =   427.31s         Find: Descendants matching type Cell
    t =   427.32s         Find: Elements containing elements matching type StaticText with identifier 'to'
    t =   427.32s         Find: Descendants matching type StaticText
```

The `(UInt) $R2 = 1` indicating that there is one static text present. However looking at the simulator I can clearly see two UILabels.

I've tried a number of things individually to isolate the issue - Using just `alpha` or setting the text to `nil`, or using UIView's `hidden` property. Using any of these options to initially hide the label renders it invisible to UI tests when later made visible, no matter what I try.

I'm quite confused by this and I suspect it's a bug. Anyone have any ideas how to get UI Tests to see the UILabel once I make it visible?

P.S. I've also tried using a wait loop to wait for the label to appear (using `expectationForPredicate(...)`, but the `UILabel` has not shown up.

Comment: Tell the label you're sorry, and maybe she'll come back ;)

Comment: try replace cell.labelText.text = nil to cell.labelText.text = ""

Comment: You might have to use `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` to wait for the label to appear. i.e. you could be finding a race condition between the app and the test.

Comment: @michael - Tried that. Didn't work. Even after 5 seconds of the label clearly being visible, the UI Test still could not see it, and the logs showed the UI test repeatedly scanning the UI hierarchy during that time.

Comment: @vien vu - Tried that as well. It made no difference as setting alpha was still making the label disappear from the hierarchy.

Comment: are you sure that the text is correct? have you tried to find label without hiding? was it successful?

Comment: YEs the text is correct. I've found that if I trigger a reloadDAta (Which I don't want to do), the UILabel becomes accessible to the UI Testing framework.

Comment: This is quite bizarre. Is it possible to post a small example to GitHub that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem turned out to be that I had not set the `accessibilityElements` property on the cells. Therefore accessibility was having issues trying to figure out what was in each one.

So if you are building custom cells for a table view, ensure you set the `accessibilityElements` property so that testing can find the contents of the cells.